# Regex :Notepad++ capture and replace every sequence of consecutive special characters as one

Tags: regex

I want to use this expression `[^\w\h ]` to capture and replace every sequence of consecutive special characters as one :

Like for example if i replace in this text:

`$$` this is a `....` text `:`

By :`*special_char*`

Result will be  :

`*special_char*` this is a `*special_char*` text `*special_char*`

Does anyone have any idea how to capture a group of consecutive matches as one match ?

Comment: You can use a capture group with an optional repeated backreference `([^\w/ ])\1*` The `h` can be omitted as `\w ` also matches it. https://regex101.com/r/4NdgnF/1

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Notepad ++

Comment: You have to select using regular expression, use `([^\w/ ])\1*` as the pattern and replace with `*special_char*`

Comment: You can post the answer and i'll mark it as correct .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group with an optional repeated backreference `\1*` to repeatedly match the same chars as a whole and also a single `:`

You can omit `h` as `\w` matches word characters.

```
([^\w/ ])\1*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4NdgnF/1/)

To match 1 or more chars other than word or whitespace chars

```
[^\w\s]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/me9n1f/1)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked.
This works for a more general case if I want to match different consecutive characters :

```
([^\w\h \n\r]+)
```